# Pandas Dataframe taking too much time to process row vector

Tags: pandas

I have Sample file with about 1000 rows and 260 columns. I want to get new values by subtracting the row mean from the cell value. Below code works fine but it takes lot of time for just 400 rows. Is there better solution to complete this task in less time?

```
import numpy as np

import xlrd

import pandas as pd

Source = xlrd.open_workbook('Sample.xlsx')

Destination = 'Destination.xlsx'

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(Destination, engine='openpyxl')

ws1 = Source.sheet_by_index(0)

nrows = ws1.nrows

ncols = ws1.ncols

Rows = pd.DataFrame(index=range(nrows), columns=range(ncols))

for i in range(nrows):

    Avg = np.mean(ws1.row_values(i))

    for j in range(ncols):

        Rows.iloc[i:,j:] = ((ws1.cell_value(i,j)-Avg))

Rows.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=0, startrow=0, index=False, header=False)

writer.save()

writer.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

why not trying to open and save your excel through **pandas** as well using

```
source = pd.read_csv(sample.xlsx)
source.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Subtract all values of `DataFrame` be mean by [`DataFrame.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sub.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'A':[4,5,4],
         'B':[7,8,9],
         'C':[1,3,5],
         'D':[5,3,6]

})

df = df.sub(df.mean(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)

      A     B     C     D
0 -0.25  2.75 -3.25  0.75
1  0.25  3.25 -1.75 -1.75
2 -2.00  3.00 -1.00  0.00
```

Do your code should be changed with [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for `DataFrame` and [`DataFrame.to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) for new excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Sample.xlsx')
df1 = df.sub(df.mean(axis=1), axis=0)
df1.to_excel( 'Destination.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: I need to calculate mean of every row then that mean be subtracted from each cell value of particular row.